# HTML - Progress bar display the "%" in text

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my progress bar. Here's the problem :

```
<b>Life of ' . stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($donnees['username'])) . ' :</b>   <progress id="progressBar" max="' . $donnees["life"] . '" value="'. $donnees["lifeac"] . '"></progress>
```

The progress bar is quite simple, and this is what it SHOULD display :

```
Life of **USER** : [Progress bar]
```

It do exactly what I wanted BUT there is the value written in %. For example, if my life is 855, it will show 855% at the right end of the progress bar. Here is the inside of my CSS :

```
progress {
  display:inline-block;
  width:190px;
  height:20px;
  padding:15px 0 0 0;
  margin:0;
  background:none;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  position:relative;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  height:11px;
  width:150px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 6px #777 inset;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  height:11px;
  margin:0px -10px 0 0;
  background: #F70;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 6px #777 inset;
}
progress:after {
  margin:-26px 0 0 -7px;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  content: attr(value) '%';
}
```

Help will be welcomed. Thanks !

Comment: Be more specific. What is the value printed? What do you like to print?

Comment: It print the progress bar with "value" in % displayed at the right end like [------]8% .                                                                                                                 I just want the progress bar, without the text like : [-------]

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the "%" sign?  Remove it from this line of the css `content: attr(value) '%';`

Comment: Oh... You are right, forgot about this... Thanks a lot :)